# What are the differences between trowels for concrete and plaster? Are they interchangeable?

Tags: concrete, tools, plaster, hand-tools

I have some paving steps to lay in concrete, and will buy a trowel for smoothing them off.

There's an enormous range of trowels/floats available, with almost identical ones for plastering and for concrete laying.   Can I use one trowel for both purposes?

General example:

[image: https://www.bunnings.co.nz/kango-280mm-gold-stainless-steel-pre-worn-plaster-trowel_p0098421]
280mm Gold Stainless Steel Pre-Worn **Plaster** Trowel $43

[image: https://www.bunnings.co.nz/kango-305mm-gold-stainless-steel-concrete-trowel_p0098449]
305mm Gold Stainless Steel Pre-Worn **Concrete** Trowel $40

This is not a direct product comparison, its a more-general "what's the difference?" question.  I see the Plaster one is 25mm shorter, but has a longer "backbone" compared to the Concrete one, which has more "fore and aft deck" (?)  exposed before the handle starts.

This is purely about rectangular floats, or smoothing trowels.   Not pointing or mortering, and not gardening/weeding.   What would stop me using the same tool for both jobs ?

Comment: Related to but not a duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48920/types-of-floats-and-trowels-for-concrete

Comment: What would stop you? Belief in marketing hype. Do you think the difference warrants buying both tools? I do not. As long as you keep the  tool clean and rust-free, it should meet both needs.

Comment: Steel trowels can be used for either plaster or concrete. Each will produce a smooth, flat surface. A wooden trowel will give a rougher/coarser finish.

Comment: Well, having noted the obvious 25mm difference, I'll point out that you failed to notice that the Plaster trowel has a cool "target" icon, while the Concrete trowel is only adorned with an underline for the company name. There's also a difference in the yellows, but I couldn't quote the Pantone numbers without looking them up.  I think that probably sums up the differences. Oh, that and $3... On the bright side, they're both made out of "Gold" (or so it seems) and that makes either a steal at only ~$40!!

Comment: Right - so its market segment flooding and there's no practical difference.

Comment: If you get a chance to compare them, is the plastering trowel a bit more curved (convex) on the working surface? Looks so from the two pics above, but maybe illusion. I've not done much plaster, but did do some concrete finishing. I'm not expert. I remember it took some pressure, the material could be stiff and heavy. The goal was to work the "cream' to the surface, pushing the rocks down and smoothing or compacting the sand & portland-mix at the surface. Plastering starts with a creamier material, with more choices of final finish.